# css boxes not scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

I am building a site for my brother and on the main page I am supposed to make a few css boxes that should be in the same position as an image that has multiple photo frames in it. I haven't picked on html and css in years and I'm having issues placing the boxes in place, especially because if I scroll, the boxes don't follow along. Here's what I have so far:

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(images/fundo2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
}

#header-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: #252525;
  text-align: center;
}

#languageflags {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}

#menu {
  overflow: visible;
  background: #252525;
  min-height: 30px;
  max-height: 66px;
  padding: 2px;
}

#page {
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
}

#linkone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 27.2%;
  width: 14%;
  height: 44%;
  padding: 1%;
  background: rgba(239, 64, 53, 0.2);
}

#linktwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47.5%;
  left: 52%;
  width: 14.5%;
  height: 30%;
  padding: 1%;
  background: rgba(239, 64, 53, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
      <div id="languageflags">place for other languages</div>
      <div id="logo">logo on header</div>
      <div id="menu" class="container">
        <ul>
          menu goes here
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--end menu-->
    </div>
    <!--end header-->
    <div id="page" class="container">
      <div id="content">
        <div id="linkone">my box attempt</div>
        <div id="linktwo">second box attempt</div>
        <img src="images/fundo.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
      </div>
      <!--end content-->
    </div>
    <!--end page container-->
  </div>
  <!--end wrapper-->
</body>
```

So the two boxes were supposed to scroll, but they stay fixed on the same position. What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the closest positioned ancestor - as you have nothing that is positioned between your links and the body, the links are positioned relative to the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to `#wrapper` selector add `position: relative`

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:url(images/fundo2.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: top;
    position: relative; /* add this line */
}
```

Comment: I would have added it to `#content` otherwise you have the same problem as now - it is placed relative to the whole page rather than just the image

Comment: thanks .. keep in mind the comment by @Pete in answer and on question